# Enable tooltips ActiveGantt 3.0.9.0

Tags: c#, winforms, gantt-chart

I'm putting together a form using the ActiveGantt 3.0.9.0 CSN control from http://www.bootes.co/EN/Default.aspx.

```
private void activeGanttCSNCtl1_OnMouseHoverToolTipDraw(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
  {
     switch (e.EventTarget)
     {
        case E_EVENTTARGET.EVT_TASK:
           TaskToolTipDraw(e);
           e.CustomDraw = true;
           return;
        case E_EVENTTARGET.EVT_SELECTEDTASK:
           TaskToolTipDraw(e);
           e.CustomDraw = true;
           return;
        case E_EVENTTARGET.EVT_PERCENTAGE:
           TaskToolTipDraw(e);
           e.CustomDraw = true;
           return;
        case E_EVENTTARGET.EVT_SELECTEDPERCENTAGE:
           TaskToolTipDraw(e);
           e.CustomDraw = true;
           return;
     }
```

However e.EventTarget refuses to trigger on tasks. I can check the value and move around the control, and I can get EVT_Clientarea, EVT_Row, EVT_Column, EVT_None, EVT_Splitter, EVT_Timeline, EVT_TimelineScrollBar to trigger. However on tasks that I have added via this function it simply states that I am in EVT_Clientarea:

```
activeGanttCSNCtl1.Tasks.Add(AddingTask.Description, AddingTask.RowKey, AddingTask.StartTime, AddingTask.EndTime, AddingTask.ID, AddingTask.Style, AddingTask.Layer);
```

The tasks all show up fine, but simply do not trigger the Task event when I mouse over. If anyone could give me any guidance as to what I'm missing I would really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking this question. Try Overriding ToolTipOnMouseHover:

```
private void ActiveGanttCSNCtl1_ToolTipOnMouseHover(object sender, AGCSN.ToolTipEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.EventTarget)
            {
                case E_EVENTTARGET.EVT_TASK:
                case E_EVENTTARGET.EVT_SELECTEDTASK:
                    ActiveGanttCSNCtl1.ToolTip.Visible = true;
                    return;
            }
            ActiveGanttCSNCtl1.ToolTip.Visible = false;
        }
```

OnMouseHoverToolTipDraw fires when the Visible property of the ToolTip object is set to true, ToolTipOnMouseHover and OnMouseHoverToolTipDraw work in conjunction. In ToolTipOnMouseHover you generally perform calculations and do the actual drawing in OnMouseHoverToolTipDraw.

In the above example OnMouseHoverToolTipDraw would only be raised for tasks and ignored for all other objects. ActiveGantt handles Tasks and Tasks that are selected as two different objects.

Best Regards,

Julio Luzardo

Boötes Systems SAS

Comment: My problem is not the location of my functions to fire my tooltips. I've got essentially the same function on ToolTipOnMouseHover already. As I said, my problem is getting e.EventTarget to ever equal EVT_TASK or EVT_SELECTEDTASK.

Comment: As a sidenote. I am also attempting to use the activeGanttCSNCtl1.MathLib.GetTaskIndexByPosition(e.X, e.Y) function for other purposes, and no matter where I click in my control, it will return -1, as it does not seem to recognize that the tasks exist even though they clearly do.

Comment: Well, I figured it out, no thanks to the makers of the tool. The LayerEnableObjects property was set to EC_INCURRENTLAYERONLY and I had the wrong layer selected as my "current" one. So you can either set this property to EC_INALLLAYERS or set your current layer to the correct one.

Not sure how to set the question to answered without giving Julio credit, as he didn't actually solve anything.

Comment: Next time provide your complete code, it is impossible to guess an answer with the little code you provided.